# FFmpeg: Zoom with xfade filter doesn't work

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I need to create a video with the ***centered Zoom In (Out)*** effect and ***xfade***

Here is the command with which I've tried to do it

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 \ 
-loop 1 -t 6 -i image1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 6 -i image2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 6 -i image3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 6 -i image4.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "
[0]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v1]; \
[1]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v2]; \
[2]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v3]; \
[3]crop=1280:1280[v4]; \
[v1][v2]xfade=rectcrop:duration=1:offset=5[x1]; \
[x1][v3]xfade=distance:duration=1:offset=10[x2]; \
[x2][v4]xfade=wiperight:duration=1:offset=15,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 4:a -b:v 4000k -movflags +faststart -s 1280x1280 out.mp4
```

And it gives the following error message

```
[Parsed_xfade_9 @ 00000146d725c400] First input link main parameters (size 1280x720) do not match the corresponding second input link xfade parameters (size 1280x1280)
[Parsed_xfade_9 @ 00000146d725c400] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_xfade_9
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #3:0
Conversion failed!
```

The image sizes are 1280x1600

Actually, I'm not sure if my Zoom filter should do a centered Zoom but seems it's decreases the image height to 720?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zoompan filter scales the input after zooming. Default size is 1280x720. Override it by adding `s=1280x1280` to the zoompan filters.

Comment: Works, thank you